# Need to get form through ajax and post it on success

Tags: jquery, ajax, post

This piece of code does not work, the get works fine, but the post is not even invoked,

```
<div id="formcontainer" ></div>


jQuery('#formcontainer').load(url,function(data){
        alert(jQuery('#actualform').serialize()+' downloaded form');

        jQuery('form#actualform').post(
            'urltoreturnjson' , function( jsondata) {
                jQuery("#jsonresp" ).html( jsondata);
            });

    });
```

the first alert works fine and i see actualform, but the post is not even invoke, 
i am missing a key understanding of how this wrks ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

[jQuery.post()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)

Change

```
jQuery('form#actualform').post(
//        ^ remove you just need $.post() or jQuery.post()
```

to

```
jQuery.post(
```

Answer (score 1):

Your usage of .post() is wrong. You do not call post on elements.
You can try as follows. See the [docs](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) for futher info.

```
jQuery('#formcontainer').load(url,function(data){
    alert(jQuery('#actualform').serialize()+' downloaded form');

    jQuery.post(
        'urltoreturnjson' , jQuery('#actualform').serialize(), function( jsondata) {
            jQuery("#jsonresp" ).html( jsondata);
        });
    });
```